# Manage localhost cookies

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My aim is to define a list of cookies in localhost domain (straight in the code) and delete it on click on the icon of the extension. I've got stuck pretty soon, it seems the function `show()` is not executed, and apparently there is no console available to check for error in chrome extensions..what's wrong with my code?

manifest

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "name": "myCookie!", 
    "description": "myCookie manager",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [ "cookies","storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" , "nativeMessaging"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["content.js"],
      "persistent": false
    }
}
```

content.js

```js
function show() {
  chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies) {
        alert(cookies)
      });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        show();
    });
});
```

popup.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my cookie</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
            margin: 5px;
        }
    h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">btn</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser action popup is a normal page so you need to load its scripts normally.

1. Remove `"background"` section in manifest.json
2. Rename content.js to popup.js
3. Add `<script src="popup.js"></script>` before the closing `</body>` tag

P.S. Instead of `alert` you can use `console.log` to print in the popup's separate devtools console so to see the output right-click inside the popup then click "Inspect".

Comment: what if I want to associate an action on cookies (add/delete) straight on click on the extension button and not in a button on the popup page?

Comment: If you still want to show the popup, simply put that code in popup.js at the beginning, that code will run automatically every time the popup is shown. If you don't want to show any popup at all then remove "default_popup" so that only `"browser_action":{}` remains and declare a background script with chrome.browserAction.onClicked listener ([examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction)).